# All connected users have LAN ipaddress (VPN)

Tags: networking, router, vpn, iptables, mikrotik-routeros

Problem: All connected clients(users) have local network IP address!

I have 1 Dedicated Server at home, and 1 VPS at hosting!
I want to make VPN server to VPS what will connect to Router.

VPS ip:
10.0.0.1 -> local network 
10.0.0.100-150 -> DHCP ip for connected clients.

Mikrotik Router ip:
192.168.1.100-150 -> DHCP
192.168.1.1 -> network

I connected my Router to VPN (i have internet, etc.) but i put port forwarding NAT, the client have option to join my server but his IP address is my Local network IP like : 10.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.1.